# Account language setting ignored in Wagtail admin for localized model names

Tags: localization, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I configured localized verbose names for my project's models, and these names are displayed correctly in Wagtail admin – but only for the `LANGUAGE_CODE` configured in `settings.py`. If I switch the individual account language in the admin web interface, the interface language changes, except for the model names.

How can I make sure the admins' choices override the global `LANGUAGE_CODE` setting?